# Javascript Greater than or less than

Tags: javascript

I did a rewrite of the code I submitted yesterday based on suggestions from others. I now have this but still can't seem to get it to work with greater than less than. I can add/substract the 2 numbers and get a valid answers. I can't get a > < to work however. Hoping someone can offer some additional help keeping it within this format of "If statements".

```
if ((input.search("what is greater")!= -1) && (input.search(/\d{1,10}/)!=-1) && (input.search(/\d{1,10}/)!=-1)) 
{var numbersInString = input.match(/\d+/g); 
var num1 = parseInt( numbersInString[0], 10 ); 
var num2 = parseInt( numbersInString[1], 10 ); 
if (num1 < num2) document.result.result.value = ""+num1+" is less than "+num2+""; 
if (num1 > num2) document.result.result.value = ""+num1+" is greater than "+num2+""; 
if (num1 = num2) document.result.result.value = "Both numbers are equal"; 
return true;}
```

Comment: How do you split into words; is the first condition already true?

Comment: You have a semi-colon after the `if`-statements with make them more or less useless

Comment: i would rethink the entire logic - try to keep DOM management and logic apart, it gets pretty complicated over time otherwise (and makes things easier to debug) ;)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to manipulate a number in two ways:

1) You want to refer to the individual characters.

2) You want to compare the number to another number and see if one is greater than another.

If you have a string called `input`, then you can use the function `parseInt(input, 10)` to convert it from a string to the number represented by that string.

If you want to get just the first two characters, you can use the `substring` function.

The important thing to keep in mind is that to the computer, the string '12345' and the number 12345 are completely different.  The computer has a completely different set of operations that it will perform on each.

also, @albin is correct to point out that putting semicolons after your `if` statements is wrong.

Comment: Based on the change suggested by CarlesAndres
isn't that what I'm doing?

Answer (score 0):

The output of the match method is an array of strings, so I think you are NOT comparing numbers but strings. Try doing this before comparing your numbers.

```
var num1 = parseInt( numbersInString[0], 10 );
var num2 = parseInt( numbersInString[1], 10 );
```

And then compare num1 and num2.

Comment: @ CarlesAndres
Tried the below it makes sense to me but still no go.
if ((input.search("what is greater")!= -1) && (input.search(/\d{1,10}/)!=-1) && (input.search(/\d{1,10}/)!=-1)) { 
var numbersInString = input.match(/\d+/g); 
var num1 = parseInt( numbersInString[0], 10 ); 
var num2 = parseInt( numbersInString[1], 10 ); 
if (num1 < num2)  
document.result.result.value = ""+num1+" is less than "+num2+""; 
if (num1 > num2)  
document.result.result.value = ""+num1+" is greater than "+num2+""; 
if (num1 = num2)  
document.result.result.value = "Both numbers are equal";   
return true;}

Comment: You should debug. Why don't you output numbersInString to the console and set a breakpoint to check its value after the assignment? I suggest you spend some minutes learning how to do this in your browser. If you don't use Google Chrome, try it, there's plenty of information about the devtools on you tube.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/qt3RW/
Simple input box:
​​​​

```
<input id="input1" value="Is 6 greater than 5"></input>
```

Parser find 'Is # greater than #' where # is digit and alert this digits:

```
var IsStringValid = $("#input1").val().match(/Is \d greater than \d/g);
alert(IsStringValid);
if(IsStringValid){
    var values = $("#input1").val().match(/\d/g);
    for(var i = 0; i < values.length; i++){
        alert(values[i])
    }
}
```

​